# ApexCharts: Grouped bar charts labeling and series

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Quick Summary:
I've been trying to build an apex column chart that shows a job performance against targets, with two grouped bars that indicated Revenue: Expected/Actual to Date, and Cost: Expected/Actual To Date.

Here is the chart I can create with ApexCharts:
[image]

And here is the one I want to build (mocked up in Excel for demonstration):
[image]

I'm struggling in that I'm not sure I'm applying the series and groups correctly to get the results I want.  Right now, it is set up to have two series, one expected (which has the expected values for both the revenue and cost) and the second for Actual (which similarly has the actual values of revenue and cost).  Then in the x-axis, I create two categories called Revenue and Cost.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var options = {
            series: [{
                    name: ['Expected'],
                    data: [3025.00, 2500.00]}, 
                {
                    name: ['Actual'], 
                    data: [896.00, 625.00]}
                ],
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 400
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function (value) {
                        if (isNaN(value)) {
                            return value;
                        } else {
                            var Formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                                style: 'currency',
                                currency: 'USD'
                            });

                            return Formatter.format(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                offsetX: -6,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    colors: ['#fff']
                },
                formatter: function (val, opt) {
                    console.log(opt.w.globals);
                    var Formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                                style: 'currency',
                                currency: 'USD'
                            });

                    //return opt.w.globals.labels[opt.dataPointIndex] + ': ' + Formatter.format(val);
                    //return opt.w.globals.seriesNames[opt.seriesIndex] + ': ' + Formatter.format(val);
                    return Formatter.format(val);
                }
            },
            stroke: {
                show: true,
                width: 1,
                colors: ['#fff']
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                intersect: false
            },
            xaxis: {
                categories: ["Revenue", "Cost"],
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#apexJobChart"), options);
        chart.render();
```

As shown in the Excel picture, I want each group to have its own series for Expected and Actual, and I'd like to show those labels on the left of the chart (I tried on the bar itself but for the green bars the size is too small).  I'd also like the colors to be different (which I think I can do with the colors array) to demonstrate how they are different series.

Any guidance is appreciated.